# Render response data through mapping to a child html element... using React and updating state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to display response data through resulting map array out to react child element (innerHTML). I am currently outputting null as the data, even tho i see the true data in the response headers.

This is the lookup Function

```
 lookup = () => {
    console.log('Step 1. Smartystreets - Define Lookup.');
    let lookup = new Lookup();
    lookup.street = this.state.shippingAddress.addressLine1;
    lookup.street2 = this.state.shippingAddress.addressLine2;
    lookup.city = this.state.shippingAddress.city;
    lookup.state = this.state.shippingAddress.state;
    lookup.zipCode = this.state.shippingAddress.zipCode;
    lookup.match = 'strict';
    lookup.maxCandidates = 1;

    console.log('Step 2. Send the lookup to smartystreets.');
    client.send(lookup)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('Step 3. Show the resulting candidate addresses:');
      console.dir(response);
      response.lookups[0].result.map(this.buildTextOutput);
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      console.warn(response);
    });
 }
 buildTextOutput = () => {
  const candidateOutput = document.getElementById("verifiedAddress");
  const outputElement = document.createElement('verifiedAddressResults');
  outputElement.innerHTML = candidate.deliveryLine1 + '<br>' + candidate.lastLine;

  candidateOutput.appendChild(outputElement);
}  
}
```

I need to output the candidate.deliveryLine1 + candidate.lastLine as react friendly so that i can present an option to the user to select the output result as the address and setState as the new response data... I think im pretty close... any help out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend avoiding manipulating the DOM directly using methods such as `.innerHTML` - React does a good job of diffing and rendering your page efficiently when left alone, but can struggle if you unexpectedly modify the DOM like this.

As for your question, I would save the response to the component's state and then map the data inline like so:

```
// in lookup function
client.send(lookup)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('Step 3. Show the resulting candidate addresses:');
      console.dir(response);
      this.setState({addresses: response.lookups[0].result})
    })

// in render function
{this.state.addresses.map((address) => {
    return (
        // Desired markup here
    )
})}
```

Comment: That worked! my next question would be if i have in the response a 4 char code to output different possible solutions say for instance code 1 = AABB (this would output - Did you forget your apartment number?) etc etc. How would you implement something like that into react?

Comment: This sounds like you'd want to create some sort of mapping between the characters like `const responses = {AABB: 'Did you forget your apartment number'}`. If you could accept my original answer I'd appreciate it :)